# Get method vs direct variable reference in Ionic framework

Tags: html, typescript, security, ionic-framework, getmethod

This is a very basic question but I am concerned about my Ionic app security.
There are two ways I can access my TypeScript class variable in HTML.

1. Direct reference

TS file:

```
appName: string = 'Test App';
```

HTML file:

```
App: <p>{{appName}}</p>
```

2. Via get method

TS file:

```
private appName: string = 'Test App';

get getAppName(){
   return this.appName;
}
```

HTML file:

```
App: <p>{{getAppName}}</p>
```

Now in few frameworks, the 2nd method is preferable as it is more secure and only gets the variable read access to the view. Is the 1st approach also secure for Ionic or I should always use the 2nd approach?

Answer (score 0):

IMO I would always use the second approach as it only has a setter method which acts on a private variable.

In the first you have a variable which is public and in theory mutatable.

also `get getAppName` is redundant. It would be more succient to simply write `get appName`